# Need to send message from a context menu to a content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a small extension that allows me to easy submit links to reddit.
This extensions adds a new context menu ('Submit Page'). If the users right clicks and selects this menu the www.redddit.com/submit page is opened in another tab, and the page from where the menu was triggered is submitted.

I've added the context menus:

**contextMenu.js**

```
// Setup where the menu is presents;
// A list of [context, context menu text, id]
var redditURL = 'http://www.reddit.com/submit';
var contexts = [["page", "Submit page", "id-submitPage"], ["link", "Submit link", "id-submitLink"], ["editable", "Submit text", "id-submitText"], ["image", "Submit image", "id-submitImage"]];

// Add all menus to their context
contexts.forEach(function(element) {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        "title" : element[1],
        "contexts" : [element[0]],
        "id" : element[2]
    });
});

// Add actions to menus
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    var submittedURL = tab && tab.url;
    if (info["menuItemId"] == "id-submitPage") {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            "url" : redditURL
        }, function(tab) {
            // After we create the tab we also send a message to the content
            // script associated with the page to intercept our info
            console.log(submittedURL);
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
                "url" : submittedURL,
                "type" : "submitPage"
            });
        });
    }
});
```

As you can in see in the addListener I am using `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` to send the URL I am submitting to the content script associated with: `redditURL` .

The content script: **contextMenu-RedditSubmit.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert('here');
    console.log(sender.tab ? "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url : "from the extension");
});
```

And the manifest file:

```
...
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["contextMenu.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://www.reddit.com/submit"],
            "js": ["contextMenu-RedditSubmit.js"],
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ],
...
```

Problem is my messages are not received inside the contextMenu-RedditSubmit.js content script. I cannot see neither the console.log nor the alert. Any tips ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your message is sent before event `document_start` content scripts execute.

To ensure it works, switch to using [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi):

```
chrome.tabs.create({
  "url" : redditURL
}, function(tab) {
  // After we create the tab we also send a message to the content
  // script associated with the page to intercept our info
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    tab.id,
    {file: "contextMenu-RedditSubmit.js"},
    function() {
      // Here, it is guaranteed that the script finished executing
      //  (or there was an error)
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
        "url" : submittedURL,
        "type" : "submitPage"
      });
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I've also modified the manifest.json and added the privileges needed for the programmatic injection.

Comment: Well, try adding error-checking. Add a callback to `sendMessage` and check `chrome.runtime.lastError` in both.